# Type '{}[]' is not assignable to type 'Observable<any[]>' in ionic 2

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic2, observable

I am working in ionic 2. I am trying to get json from firebase. I have used observable but showing me error. here is my home.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController } from 'ionic-angular';
import { DetailsPage} from'../details/details';
import { MyProvider } from '../../providers/my/my';
import  'rxjs/Rx';
import {Observable} from 'rxjs/Observable';
@Component({
  selector: 'page-home',
  templateUrl: 'home.html'
})
export class HomePage {
    donorList: Observable<any[]>;
 constructor(public nav: NavController, public data: MyProvider) {
    this.data.loadData().subscribe(k => {
   this.donorList = k;
});      
   }
```

}

my json file is

```
{
    "s2pDonors": [{
            "name": "Dinesh",
            "bldgrp": "o+",
            "city": "Nagpur"

        }, {
            "name": "Dinesh",
            "bldgrp": "o+",
            "city": "Nagpur"
        },
        {
            "name": "Suresh",
            "bldgrp": "A+",
            "city": "Nagpur"
        },

    ]
}
```

while creating android .apk file it showing me following error

```
Type '{}[]' is not assignable to type 'Observable<any[]>'.

      L64:   this.data.loadData().subscribe(k => {
      L65:  this.donorList = k;
      L66:   console.log(this.donorList);
```

my provider in whichthe loadData() function is defined is given

```
export class MyProvider {
    list : Array<any>;
  constructor(public afd: AngularFireDatabase) {
}
loadData()
  {
    return this.afd.list('/s2pDonors/').valueChanges();
  };
  }
```

anyone can help...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your constructor you're subscribing to an Observable, so the data you're receiving from that Observable **IS NOT AN OBSERVABLE**. In other words the variable **K** is not an observable. So you need to remove **Observable** from **dataList**.
Here is the code you need to change

```
export class HomePage {
    donorList;
 constructor(public nav: NavController, public data: MyProvider) {
    this.data.loadData().subscribe(k => {
   this.donorList = k;
});      
   }
```

### PS:

If you wanted to return an Observable you need to subscribe to a Subject. Here's more info about [Observable vs Subject](http://javascript.tutorialhorizon.com/2017/03/23/rxjs-subject-vs-observable/)

Comment: @FaisalAmdani  If this answer works mark it as correct to help others.